# Codeigniter: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(row)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's the code I'm using 
Models folder

```
    class Data_model extends CI_Model {
        function getAll(){
            $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
            if($q->num_rows()>0){
                foreach($q->result() as $row) 
                {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
        }
    }
```

View folder

```
    <p><?php foreach($row as $r){
    echo '<h1>'. $r->title .'</h1>';
    }
    ?></p>
```

Controller folder

```
    function index() {
        $this->load->model('data_model');
        $data['row'] = $this->data_model->getAll();   
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/home.php

Line Number: 10
```

Comment: Can you do a var_dump to "$row" ?

Comment: The answer is you are not getting any results from the query. Then the foreach is dying because $row contains no value and a warning is thrown by the foreach.

Comment: Shawn is probably right, since you have no data, "$data" is never used and probably "null" that's why is an invalid argument for a foreach.

Comment: Try the below code which I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
foreach($q->result() as $row) 
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

try this

```
    $data['row'] = $q->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Active record class

Your model:

```
public function getAll()
{
 $query = $this->db->get("users");
 return $query->result_array();
}
```

View file:

```
 foreach($row as $item)
  echo $item['title'];
```